# Where can I see volcanic rivers in Iceland?

Tags: where-on-earth, iceland, volcanoes, rivers

A Google search for ["volcanic rivers" iceland] returns a lot of results, with some amazing images like this:

[image: Volcanic river]

But I have not been able to find any information on **where** you can see volcanic rivers in Iceland. And "near some volcano" is not good enough - I want to know a specific location. I am planning to travel to Iceland later this year and want to see if this is something I can work into my itinerary.

Comment: LMGTFY [Rivers in Iceland](https://cometoiceland.is/nature-in-iceland/rivers-in-iceland/) and [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rivers_of_Iceland)

Comment: @Dorothy I was asking specifically about **volcanic** rivers, not rivers generally...

Comment: If you're trying to see them as Russian photographer Andre Ermolaev did in in his series of aerial images of rivers flowing through beds of volcanic ash, you'll have to time your visit to the summer months when the melt from the glaciers create the flow. The Land of Fire and Ice has massive glaciers and 30 volcanic systems, so these randomly occur as nature dictates. Ermolaev shot those images flying over the southern coast and and in the central highlands of the Iceland. Go in the summer and go to the volcanic belt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my visit in Iceland, the area towards the coast [between **Kálfafell** and **Hof**](https://www.google.com/maps/place/63%C2%B051'22.6%22N+17%C2%B002'16.7%22W/@63.9008452,-17.5514495,9.3z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d63.856275!4d-17.037984?hl=de) came to mind:

[image: Kálfafell]

<sup>Image source: [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/63%C2%B051'22.6%22N+17%C2%B002'16.7%22W/@63.9008452,-17.5514495,9.3z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d63.856275!4d-17.037984?hl=de)</sup>

---

And looking at [this geotagged photo by Andre Ermolaev](https://500px.com/photo/134854291/the-painting-of-the-river-by-andre-ermolaev?ctx_page=1&from=user&user_id=260790), that seems to be pretty much exactly where he took it (note that most of these are *aerial* shots though).

I'd imagine there's plenty more places like this, but I remembered this area because it's easily accessible - on the **ring road**, you basically drive right trough a massive black sand beach / mudflat with rivers meandering through it towards the coast.

You can even make out some of these structures from the satellite imagery on Google maps:

[image: Volcanic River near Kálfafell]

<sup>Image source: [Google Maps](https://www.google.ch/maps/place/K%C3%A1lfafell,+Island/@63.9257891,-17.4071401,2766m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x48d055c1d7a311e9:0x808ac667863073ef!8m2!3d63.9394841!4d-17.7113342!6m1!1e1)</sup>

---

[image: Volcanic River near Kálfafell 2]

<sup>Image source: [Google Maps](https://www.google.ch/maps/place/K%C3%A1lfafell,+Island/@63.7392734,-17.807722,1134m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x48d055c1d7a311e9:0x808ac667863073ef!8m2!3d63.9394841!4d-17.7113342!6m1!1e1)</sup>

Comment: Great answer! Sourced, visually-aided, exactly what I wanted to know!